# qsub for one machine?

Tags: multiprocessing

A frequent problem I encounter is having to run some script with 50 or so different parameterizations. In the old days, I'd write something like (e.g.)

```
for i in `seq 1 50`
do
    ./myscript $i
done
```

In the modern era though, all my machines can handle 4 or 8 threads at once. The scripts aren't multithreaded, so what I want to be able to do is run 4 or 8 parameterizations at a time, and to automatically start new jobs as the old ones finish. I can rig up a haphazard system myself (and have in the past), but I suspect that there must be a linux utility that does this already. Any suggestions?

Comment: sudo apt-get install gridengine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GNU parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) does this. With it, your example becomes:

```
parallel ./myscript -- `seq 1 50`
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted. Should be: parallel -j 4 ./myscript -- `seq 1 50` 

though

Comment: Whoops, couldn't test it at work. Fixed the example. Default for -j is the number of cores, so this isn't strictly needed.

Comment: The arguments have to be specified following a '--' on the commandline, rather than piped in too. Also, in my example above it should be `seq 1 50`.